# How to manage PHP memory?

Tags: php, session, memory-management, memory-limit

I wrote a one-off script that I use to parse PDFs saved on the database. So far it is working okay until I ran out of memory after parsing 2,700+ documents.

The basic flow of the script is as follows:

1. Get a list of all the document IDs to be parsed and save it as an array in the session (~155k documents).
2. Display a page that has a button to start parsing
3. Make an AJAX request when that button is clicked that would parse the first 50 documents in the session array

---

```
$files = $_SESSION['files'];

$ids = array();

$slice = array_slice($files, 0, 50);
$files = array_slice($files, 50, null); // remove the 50 we are parsing on this request

if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
}
$_SESSION['files'] = $files;
session_write_close();

for($i = 0; $i < count($slice); $i++) {
  $ids[] = ":id_{$i}";
}
$ids = implode(", ", $ids);

$sql = "SELECT d.id, d.filename, d.doc_content
  FROM proj_docs d
  WHERE d.id IN ({$ids})";

$stmt = oci_parse($objConn, $sql);
for($i = 0; $i < count($slice); $i++) {
  oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":id_{$i}", $slice[$i]);
}
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
$cnt = oci_fetch_all($stmt, $data);
oci_free_statement($stmt);

# Do the parsing..
# Output a table row..
```

---

4. The response to the AJAX request typically includes a status whether the script has finished parsing the total ~155k documents - if it's not done, another AJAX request is made to parse the next 50. There's a 5 second delay between each request.

### Questions

- Why am I running out of memory when I was expecting that peak memory usage would be when I get a list of all the document IDs on `#1` since it holds all of the possible documents **not** a few minutes later when the session array holds 2,700 elements less?
- I saw a few questions similar to my problem and they suggested to either set the memory to `unlimited` which I don't want to do at all. The others suggested to set my variables to `null` when appropriate and I did that but I still ran out of memory after parsing ~2,700 documents. So what other approaches should I try?

---

```
# Freeing some memory space
$batch_size = null;
$with_xfa = null;
$non_xfa = null;
$total = null;
$files = null;
$ids = null;
$slice = null;
$sql = null;
$stmt = null;
$objConn = null;
$i = null;
$data = null;
$cnt = null;
$display_class = null;
$display = null;
$even = null;
$tr_class = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not really sure why but reducing the number of documents I'm parsing from `50` down to `10` for each batch seems to fix the issue. I've gone past 5,000 documents now and the script is still running. My only guess is that when I was parsing 50 documents I must have encountered a lot of large files which used up all of the memory allotted.

### Update #1

I got another error about memory running out at 8,500+ documents. I've reduced the batches further down to `5` documents each and will see tomorrow if it goes all the way to parsing everything. If that fails, I'll just increase the memory allocated temporarily.

### Update #2

So it turns out that the only reason why I'm running out of memory is that we apparently have multiple PDF files that are over 300MB uploaded on to the database. I increased the memory allotted to PHP to 512MB and this seems to have allowed me to finish parsing everything.